# Eigenvalue of Hermitian block matrix with scaled all-ones block

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, hermitian-matrices

Let us consider a Hermitian block matrix
\begin{align}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
A_{1,1} & \cdots & A_{1,n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
A_{n,1} & \cdots & A_{n,n}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
with $A_{i,j} = a_{i,j} J_{d_i,d_j}$ where $a_{i,j}\in \mathbb{C}$ and $J_{d_i,d_j}$ is the all-ones matrix of size $d_i\times d_j$. Each block of the matrix is essentially a scalar in that $A$ shares the eigenvalues with
\begin{align}
A^{\sf small} = \begin{bmatrix}
d_1 a_{1,1} & \cdots & \sqrt{d_1d_n}a_{1,n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\sqrt{d_nd_1} a_{n,1} & \cdots & d_n a_{n,n}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
It can be easily derived from the observation that
\begin{align}
A = DA^{\sf small}D^\top
\end{align}
where $D = \operatorname{blkdiag}\Big(\frac{J_{d_1,1}}{\sqrt{d_1}},\ldots,\frac{J_{d_n,1}}{\sqrt{d_n}}\Big)$ is a block diagonal matrix.

Plugging it into the spectral decomposition $A^{\sf small} =\sum_n \lambda_n u_n u_n^*$,
we obtain
\begin{align}
A = \sum_n \lambda_n (Du_n) (Du_n)^*.
\end{align}
Since $\{Du_n\}$ are orthonormal from $D^TD = I$, it is an eigendecomposition of $A$, which concludes the proof.

I need this small result as a lemma but it is rather trivial and I do not want to reinvent the wheel. Could you recommend a reference?